The move semantics and time complexity of nested std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> rvalue assignment
If there is function with the following signature:
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> some_func();
And its assigned to a variable of the same type:
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> var = some_func();
What would be the time complexity of this assignment operation. The obvious assumption is this will be a move assignment operation and will be faster than a regular element by element copy into var.
But I am not sure if the move assignment operation will only move the location/size information of the outer vector to var and let the pointers and size information of the inner vectors be the same, or would the inner vectors be also moved element by element?
If that is the case, would the rvalue referencing be faster? :
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>&& var = some_func();

The move constructor of std::vector<T> moves the size and the internal pointer and that's all. It doesn't care about what T is.

If the result of  some_func is a prvalue, then a direct initialization happens at absolute zero cost. Rvalue reference usage needs extreme caution to avoid dangling in specific senarios. Unless the objective is not to get a jagged array, vector of vectors is not encouraged; for 2D arrays, a single flat vector and the row size need be kept. You can std::views::chunk it on indexing/iteration.

@Red.Wave Is std::views::chunk considered better than mdspan now?

I don't like mdspan. I mean whats the catch? I can use a fold expression of chunk s to emulate the mdspan. It allows to aquire adapters on individual dimensions. All mdspan offers is a fancy indexing operator([]); is it really anything more than syntactic suger? With chunk I have all std algorithms at my disposal; what can I do with mdspan?

@Red.Wave you can use all the same algorithms with mdspan, and it's a fair bit less ceremony, especially if you use layout_left. chunk is more general in what it accepts, as it only needs input_range, not contiguous_range.

@caleth the problem with mdspan is its complexity. I can define my::mdspan in terms of chunk. It is very simple to manipulate. But std::mdspan is a pain in the neck.

@Red.Wave I guess you only care about layout_right? and you don't mix dynamic and static extents? Yes, if you strip out major features, you get something simpler.

@Caleth I am concerned about having to index mdspan. From a safety point of view, I find ranges much better than iterators and iterators slightly better than indice. Iterators and indice have the common caveat of out of bounds.

And mdspan has no plans to merge with ranges. That means the flexibility is going to remain limited for an indefinitely long duration. In the meantime with a little push, I can kickstart everything with chunk. Who knows; maybe C++32 gives us a moderately usable mdspan.


std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> var = some_func();

What would be the time complexity of this assignment operation.

There is no assignment operation.
This isn't assignment, it is copy-initialization.
See What is the difference between initialization and assignment?
Since some_func returns a std::vector by value, the returned object from some_func is the same object as var.
See also How does guaranteed copy elision work?
Prior to C++17, this would have at worst been one call to the move constructor, which has constant complexity (see (8)).

If that is the case, would the rvalue referencing be faster? :
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>&& var = some_func();


No, this is exactly as expensive as var.
This materializes the temporary object returned by some_func(), but just as in the first example, there is exactly one object.
This code is strictly worse since C++17 because it is more complex without anything gained.
Last but not least, it's quite likely that you don't need a std::vector of vectors.
This would be a 2D data structure where every row can be a different length, and that's rarely desirable.
A simpler form would be a single std::vector, wrapped in std::mdspan, std::views::chunk, et al. as needed.
